# Setting a custom tab order in a Cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, tabbing

I have a window with two columns of fields. On the left, there is an `NSTableView` and an `NSTokenField`, and on the right, there are two `NSTextField`s. I want the tab order to go down the left, then down the right. (So the order should be `NSTableView`, `NSTokenField`, `NSTextField`, `NSTextField` in my window.)  However, Cocoa appears to be determining its own preferred order, going from the top to the bottom. The `NSTokenField` is positioned lower in the window than any other control, so it will always tab from `NSTableView`, to the right `NSTextField`s, then back to the bottom left `NSTokenField`.

I have tried following this section of the Apple developer documentation called [Enable Tabbing Between Text Fields](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/05View/05View.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000863-CH7-SW11) and dragging nextKeyView in Interface Builder between the fields in the order that I want. This seems to have absolutely zero effect on the tab order, and from what I can tell, Cocoa appears to still use its default detecting method to choose a tab order.

Any ideas? My target is 10.6+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you also set the `initialFirstResponder` outlet of the window to the first field (the table view in this case).

Comment: Thanks... this was the problem. I do feel a bit silly though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're going to have to do it programmatically:
Register for `controlTextDidEndEditing` notifications, identify the field by tag, and then call `makeFirstResponder:fieldOfYourChoice` on the window. And/or use an `IBAction` on the field, identifying it by `sender`, and call `makeFirstResponder`.

Comment: Why do I have to do it programmatically? What if the user wants to shift+tab? For what it's worth, I did try this, but it didn't work. One problem is that NSTableView doesn't send a controlTextDidEndEditing notification to its delegate when you tab away from it. Even on the NSTokenField and NSTextFields, which do fire off the notification, the makeFirstResponder message did not seem to change the tab order. Finally, I'm not sure using IBAction on the fields would work for me because I think that would fire when the enter key was pressed, and I don't want to change fields when enter is pressed.

Comment: If nothing else works, you could try capturing key events. All your controls are subclasses of NSResponder, so if you subclass them, you can customize NSResponder's keyUp method. Test if the event is a tab or shift-tab. If not, do nothing. If so, find out from the window which control has firstResponder status so you know where you are, and go from there. (For this to work, you do have to be able to use makeFirstResponder. It’s worked for me for both buttons and textfields. Maybe try adding a 0.1 delay?) Also, you probably need to remove conflicting nextKeyViews in IB.